# How to Initialize structure that includes unique items out of multiple elements

Tags: c, structure

I have 4 arrays that represent:

1. Colour (r , g, b, y)
2. Shape (A , B , C, D)
3. Number (1 , 2 , 3, 4)
4. Texture (a, b , c, d)

and also each array can have 4 values. 
I want to have in an array all the possible combinations of all these elements. 
For example rA1a, rB1a,rC1a and so on.
I am thinking of creating a structure and then somehow create these 256 elements of the structure.
However **I am totally blind to how I can do this—I mean create the 256 elements**! Can someone please point me in the right direction?

The struct I am thinking of is like this, but maybe a structure is not what I need? 
What I intent to do next is then randomly pick some of these 256 elements, and put the selected ones in a 2d array to manipulate them even further. But first things first!

```
typedef struct                 
    {
    char colour;
    char shape;
    char nr;
    char texture;
    }ST1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution builds on the idea that each element has four possibilities. If we get 2 bits to represent each element, a struct of bitfields can be used, and as an 8-bit value, the 256 values represent all of the possibilites. To make initialisation easier, I have put them in a `union`.

Instead of working with the item descriptions themselves, that is left for the output to translate.

If you wanted to work with them more directly you could set up `enum`s such as `enum colours { col_r, col_g, col_b, col_y }` and so on.

Note that the descriptor `'b'` is duplicated in the problem statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef union {
    unsigned char val;
    struct {
        unsigned char colour: 2;
        unsigned char shape: 2; 
        unsigned char nr: 2;
        unsigned char texture: 2;        
    } bits;
} ST1;

const char colch [4] = { 'r', 'g', 'b', 'y' };      // descriptions
const char shpch [4] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
const char numch [4] = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };
const char texch [4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };

void show(ST1 rec)
{
    printf("%c%c%c%c\n", colch[rec.bits.colour], shpch[rec.bits.shape],
                         numch[rec.bits.nr],     texch[rec.bits.texture]);
}

int main(void)
{
    ST1 feature[256];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        feature[i].val = i;           // initiliase all perms
    }

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        show(feature[ rand() % 256 ]);
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
rD4a
bC4d
rB2c
bB4b
bD3a
```

Comment: Thank you ! This seems to work out nicely for printing some random elements!  Instead of printf do you thing it would be possible to write these values to the List permanently or even better transfer the output to a 2d array [3][4]  for example, which is my ultimate goal?

Comment: Each combo can be represented by a single `unsigned char` if you find that easier to manipulate. You don't have to use the `union` unless you want access individual members. Or you could have your array as say, `ST1 array2D[3][4]` and get accustomed to working with a `union`. Also, you could simplify it by reverting to a simpler bitfield `struct` without the `union`. I only did it that way to make it easy to initialise. I could have used 4 nested loops instead, to permute the four members' values.

Comment: I am trying to work it out with a simpler struct to see how it will work out..  Do you think that the duplicate "b" is a problem for random nr generation? This is the values I was given though!

Comment: No - just an observation - for interpretation if your program tries to figure out what a `'b'` means without context.

Comment: I have never used unions again so I am trying to see how it works.. If I want to change the show function to store function for example and put 256 values inside the array, can I use a function that includes something like:      strcpy(bits[i].colour,colour[rec.bits.colour]);
    strcpy(bits[i].shape,shape[rec.bits.shape]);
    strcpy(bits[i].nr,nr[rec.bits.nr]
    strcpy(bits[i].texture,texture[rec.bits.texture]);   It doesn't seem to work out

Comment: If you want a string for use such as `"gC3a"`, it must have length `[5]` and you can make one like I did in `show` by using `sprintf`. Perhaps `char pattern[256][5]; ... sprintf(pattern[0], " ... ", ... )`.

Answer (score 1):

First, in C, if you want to access your struct as ST1, you need to define it like this:

```
typedef struct ST1 {
    char colour;
    char shape; 
    char nr;
    char texture;        
} ST1;
```

Second, this is a fine way to do that. But you might prefer to use enums for the values of colour, shape, number, and texture. Define an enum like this:

```
enum colour_t { COLOUR_R, COLOUR_G, COLOUR_B, COLOUR_Y };
```

And use it like this:

```
enum colour_t c = COLOUR_R;
```

In response to your comment, I think it is not necessary for you to instantiate all 256 possibilities, but instead to create them on demand. Like so:

```
ST1 MakeST1FromOrdinal(char n) {
    ST1 retval;
    retval.colour = n & 0x03;
    retval.shape = (n & 0x0C) >> 2;
    retval.nr = (n & 0x30) >> 4;
    retval.texture = (n & 0xC0) >> 6;
    return retval;
}

void main() {
    char ordinal = random() % 256;
    ST1 randomResult = MakeST1FromOrdinal(ordinal);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas of how to take all the possible combination of elements for each node of the structure?

Comment: If you want to have all 256 possibilities instantiated, you could either create them with 4 nested loops, or change the representation completely so that a single char represents ST1. There are 256 possible values for char, and you can use functions like getColour(char ST1) to get all the properties using bit masks. However, I fail to see why it is useful to have all the possible values instantiated, instead of just making them _possible_ values of the same structure, to be used when needed.

Comment: As I said, I want to have all these combinations, because all of them will be used. In the next stage, I will pick randomly some of these combinations and will insert them at a 2d array, the user will select 2 of these combinations, and then I will start comparing the elements(colour etc) inside the combinations !

Comment: Ok, I think my edit shows how to get random combinations without having to make all of them in memory. This way would work just as well if there were a billion possibilities as it does with 256.

Comment: The structure in the question without the tag is perfectly legitimate and can only be referenced by the typedef name `ST1`.  In your answer, you have `typedef struct ST1 { … } ST1;` which creates a tagged structure type that can be referred to as `ST1` (the typedef name, as before) or as `struct ST1`.  You imply that the tag is compulsory; it is not compulsory.  It is entirely optional.

Comment: Well for some reason the above code gives me an undefined reference to random. !

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you would have your own way to generate a random number. You can use rand() if you include stdlib.h https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm

Comment: @baskon1: Some systems provide a function `random()` that is usually a better quality PRNG than the standard C `rand()` function.  Other systems don't.  Yours seems to be in the latter category.

Comment: Also, C99 does not support anonymous structs. Apparently C11 does though, didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

You can take an array of `structure`s! Just do this:

```
 struct abc         
    {
    char colour;
    char shape; 
    char nr;
    char texture;        
    } ST1[256];
```

If you want to access the `shape` of the 5th array, then write: `ST1[4].shape`.

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas of how I can create these 256 unique elements out of the 4 available options for each element variable?

Comment: Note that this has lost the `typedef` and created an array with the old `typedef` name.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an array of structures and use bit manipulation for reduced size as:-

```
struct abc         
    {
    int colour : 2;
    int shape : 2; 
    int number : 2;
    int texture : 2;        
    } S[256];
```

since you had only 4 values for each of your variables only 2 bits for each of them would suffice.

You can access them in the normal way as structures are used using the (.) operator or the structure pointer(->) operator.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(struct abc)` would be `sizeof(int)`; to compact it to 1 byte, you'd need to use `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` in place of `int`.  Bit fields are funny (as in, funny peculiar, not funny ha-ha) critters.